# How can I automate the "Clear Cache" everyday?

Tags: caching, cron

Currently we have to clear it manually everyday logging in to admin console and browsing to Home->Administration->Configuration->Development->Performance

Is there way we can automate this job in Drupal 8. We tried with "cron", but that didn't help.

Comment: "We tried with "cron", but that didn't help." - you're certain you had a cronjob for drush cr?

Comment: What did you try with cron that didn't work?

Comment: `crontab -e` and then maybe `0 0 * * * cd /var/www/drupal && drush cr`?

Answer (score 6):

Despite you saying it didn't work with cron, I would suggest using cron in some way.  :)

The CacheFlush module claims to allow configuration of this via its UI (although I haven't used it so cannot personally vouch for it).

If you are implementing custom code, [drupal_flush_all_caches()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_flush_all_caches/8.6.x) will handle the flushing for you.

The Rules module also allows acting on Cron runs. Using rules you could either [write a custom action](https://fago.gitbooks.io/rules-docs/content/extending_rules/rules_action_plugins.html) that uses drupal_flush_all_caches() or find a module that provides one (I haven't seen any for D8 but that doesn't necessarily mean one doesn't exist).

You could also potentially do it outside of Drupal, using a cron job on your server to call `drush cr` for your site.

**Aside:** I would suggest also considering why you need to do this and what alternatives there are. I can't really think of many (any?) cases where I would want to do this instead of just invalidating the cache of specific content entities/pages as they are changed.